# Appending an array created with a loop to another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array

```
$variables_a = array(
   'a' => $a,
   'b' => $b,
   'c' => $c
);
```

and then another `$variables_b = array('x','y','z')` and I want to loop through the B array like so:

```
foreach($variables_b as $var) {
    $variables_c[] = array($var => $$var);
}
```

and then merge A & C together with `$variables_combined = array_merge($variables_A, $variables_C)`

The output I'm hoping to get is when I `print_r` is

```
Array
(
     [a] => a
     [b] => b
     [c] => c
     [x] => x
     [y] => y
     [z] => z
)
```

but what I get is

```
Array
(
     [a] => a
     [b] => b
     [c] => c
     [0] => Array
         (
            [x] => x
         )    
     [1] => Array
         (
            [y] => y
         )    
     [2] => Array
         (
            [z] => z
         )    
)
```

If I change `$feature_variables[] = array($feature => $$feature)` to `$feature_variables = array($feature => $$feature)` I get

```
Array
(
     [a] => a
     [b] => b
     [c] => c
     [z] => z
)
```

i.e. the last item from `$variables_b` but none of the others. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please loop through array c like:

```
foreach($variables_b as $var) {
    $variables_c[$var] = $$var;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do this :

```
$newvar = $variables_a;

foreach($variables_b as $var)
{
$newvar[$var] = $var;
}
```

$newvar will contain the array you want

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
foreach($variables_b as $var) {
   $variables_c[$var] = $$var;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$variables_a = array(
   'a' ,
   'b' ,
   'c'
);

$variables_b = array('x','y','z');
 $variables_c=array();

foreach($variables_a as $var) {
    $variables_c[$var] =$var;

}

foreach($variables_b as $var) {
    $variables_c[$var] =$var;

}
print_r($variables_c);

?>
============
and test in : "http://codepad.org/1ICZxPIG"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$variables_a = array(
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b,
    'c' => $c
);
$variables_b = array('x','y','z');

foreach($variables_b as $var) {
$variables_c[$var] = $$var;
}


$variables_combined = array_merge($variables_a, $variables_c);

echo "<pre>";print_r($variables_combined);
```